# OneDrive for Business using LiveSDK?

Tags: office365, live-sdk, onedrive

We have developped a windows application to upload/download file on a OneDrive account using LiveSDK, but now we need to migrate to OneDrive for Business, is there a way to keep using LiveSDK or we absolutely need to rewrite the code to use Office 365 api ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, the LiveSDK doesn't support OneDrive for Business so you will need to rewrite code for the Files REST API.

Comment: By the way, the new OneDrive API (http://dev.onedrive.com) uses OData (same as OneDrive for Business) so it will be a lot easier for you to move later on if you choose to.